# Combining vector and raster tiles in mbtiles file?

Tags: mbtiles

I have 4 mbtiles files..

1. OSM Streets for the State of Ohio (vector)
2. Hillshading for the State of Ohio (raster)
3. Contours for the State of Ohio (vector)
4. Custom layer I imported from a Shapefile containing lines (vector)

I am wanting to use these as an offline map in an iOS app.  Can I somehow combine these into a single mbtiles file?

I used a patch script I found on github, all tiles are there, but not the metadata for them (It only lists vector), I opened it in DBBrowser and can view the hillshade blobs. Is there a tool to combine these?

Answer (score 1):

Use geopackage another sqlite container supports multiple tables both raster tiles, vector features and vector tiles GEOJSON and terrain tiles. You will need to flip Y since gpkg uses XYZ not TMS tiling schema. Several tools can convert but you can also use a sqlite editor and sqlite3. If you want one tiles table use mapproxy to create new mbtiles